# Jquery Formatting - run function after another one has finished

Tags: jquery

I have two jQuery functions. The first one below I want to run first, than when that function has finished, run the other one. Normally I'd add a function to the first bit of code, but not sure how I'd do that with this block or if it's the correct way.

So in short, I want this code to run...

```
$('#setupPanel').modal({
        backdrop: "static",
        keyboard: false
});
```

AFTER this function has finished executing...

```
$('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#header_wrap").offset().top
}, 600);
```

**EDIT:**
Here's the entire function...

```
$(setUp).click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#header_wrap").offset().top
    }, 600);
    $('#setupPanel').modal({
        backdrop: "static",
        keyboard: false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try [`promise()`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) method:

```
$(setUp).click(function () {
    $('#setupPanel').modal({
        backdrop: "static",
        keyboard: false
    }).promise().done(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#header_wrap").offset().top
        }, 600);    
      });
});
```

**Update:**

You can also use `.animate()` method's callback function:

```
$(setUp).click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#header_wrap").offset().top
        }, 600, function() {
          $('#setupPanel').modal({
              backdrop: "static",
              keyboard: false
          })
      }});
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate how this would work? Where do I put in the .modal() function? Put this under the modal.() function?

Comment: @MikeBarwick yes, put this after calling `modal()`

Comment: Not working man. I edited my post to include the entire function for your review. They're both running simultaneously still.

Comment: Negative. I need on button click (which is the setUp variable), to scroll to the top of the page (if not there already) and THEN once at the top of the page execute the modal pop-up. Right now they're both running at the same time. which kind of works, but doesn't if Im further down the page.

Comment: @MikeBarwick in this case you can try animate callback function which will be executed once the animation is completed.